# data.table merge produces extra columns [R]

Tags: r, merge, data.table

Below I define a master dataset of dimensions 12x5. I divide it into four data.tables and I want to merge them. There is no row ID overlap between data.tables and some column name overlap. When I merge them, `merge()` doesn't recognize column name matches, and creates new columns for every column in each data.table. The final merged data.table should be 12x5, but it is coming out as 12x7. I thought that the `all=TRUE` command in data.table's `merge()` would solve this.

```
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3),  C1 = c(1, 2, 3))
b <- data.table(id = c(4, 5, 6),  C1 = c(1, 2, 3),  C2 = c(2, 3, 4))
c <- data.table(id = c(7, 8, 9),  C3 = c(5, 2, 7))
d <- data.table(id = c(10, 11, 12),  C3 = c(8, 2, 3), C4 = c(4, 6, 8))

setkey(a, "id")
setkey(b, "id")
setkey(c, "id")
setkey(d, "id")

final <- merge(a, b,  all = TRUE)
final <- merge(final, c,  all = TRUE)
final <- merge(final, d,  all = TRUE)

names(final)
dim(final)  #outputs correct numb of rows, but too many columns
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with the way you are using the 'merge' function.
'merge' function in data.table package by default merges two data tables by the "shared key columns between them". Suppose you create 'a' and 'b' data tables like this:

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3),  C1 = c(1, 2, 3))
b <- data.table(id = c(4, 5, 6),  C1 = c(1, 2, 3),  C2 = c(2, 3, 4))
setkey(a, "id")
setkey(b, "id")
```

where 'a' is going to be like:

```
   id C1
1:  1  1
2:  2  2
3:  3  3
```

and 'b' is going to be like:

```
   id C1 C2
1:  4  1  2
2:  5  2  3
3:  6  3  4
```

now, lets first try your code:

```
merge(a, b,  all = TRUE)
```

This is the result:

```
   id C1.x C1.y C2
1:  1    1   NA NA
2:  2    2   NA NA
3:  3    3   NA NA
4:  4   NA    1  2
5:  5   NA    2  3
6:  6   NA    3  4
```

This is due to the fact that 'merge' function is taking only 'id' field (shared key between data tables 'a' and 'b') as the merging column, while adding all non-shared columns to the resulting data table. Now lets try specifying what columns to merge on:

```
merge(a, b, by=c("id","C1"), all = TRUE)
```

now the result is going to be:

```
   id C1 C2
1:  1  1 NA
2:  2  2 NA
3:  3  3 NA
4:  4  1  2
5:  5  2  3
6:  6  3  4
```

Same applies to other merge functions you called. So try this:

```
final <- merge(a, b, by=c("id","C1"), all = TRUE)
final <- merge(final, c, by="id", all = TRUE)  #here you don't necessarily need to specify by...
final <- merge( final, d, by=c("id","C3"),all=TRUE)

dim(final)
[1] 12  5
```

Comment: Does this generalize to scenarios where the two data.tables have many columns? Do we need to insert the name of all columns into the `by` field?

Comment: Yes. Call ?data.table::merge in R and see the arguments section, under 'by' it describes the default merging column. There's actually a trick for it that I don't recommend, or be careful when you use it. The trick is to set all columns of data table 'a' as its key, and do the same for 'b'. You can do this if your data tables have huge number of columns: setkeyv(a, names(a)); setkeyv(b, names(b)); merge(a, b, all=TRUE)

Comment: @cherrypoppindaddies why not instead use: `merge(a, b, by = intersect(names(a), names(b)))`?

Comment: Sure! For this case your approach is the best. However, sometimes I may not want to join by all the matching columns, rather I may want to pick some of them.